# How to fix wood shingle that's coming up?

Tags: carpentry, siding

Had the house power-washed today in preparation for an exterior paint job. Afterwards I noticed a couple of the wood siding shingles popping up a bit (see below). Presumably they knocked them out of place a bit while washing. [image: siding] What's the right way to push that back down? Is there a nail somewhere I can nail back down? It is some sort of adhesive that I need to apply?

Comment: Did you intend to add a picture?

Comment: Is that really wood? If older it looks like asbestos, if newer some type of concrete, in any case put some adhesive calk at the bottom end and press down until cured should hold it in place.

Comment: @JonCuster, pretty sure there's a picture there. Maybe the issue is on your end?

Comment: @EdBeal, thanks. I don't know for sure if it's wood, maybe it's not. The house was built around `91 so I'm assuming it's not asbestos. Is there an adhesive caulk you would recommend for this in particular? The caulk aisle at Lowe's can be intimidating.

Comment: If built in 91 not asbestos probably a man made material. I say this as the groves are two uniform for wood, I mentioned asbestos as those siding shingles were popular in the Pacific Northwest 50’s-60’s.

Comment: FWIW, those are "HardieShingles (r)" a cement board product. If it is not a Hardie product, it is one of their competitors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could squirt a little "glob" of construction adhesive behind it and tape it down overnight to dry. A couple small nails would work too, but they'll be subtly visible until you paint the house.